# Unity c# xmlDocument and Resources.Load/Unload

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine, resources, save

I working with `XmlDocument`.

```
TextAsset _textAsset = (TextAsset)Resources.Load(PathOfFile);
_xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
_xmlDoc.LoadXml(_textAsset.text);
```

After, I make some changes in `_xmlDoc` and save it through:

```
_xmlDoc.Save(PathOfFile);
```

But the changes are applying only if I reopen XML file from Explorer or hide-show Unity.

So I think problem is: the file is still open after `Resources.Load`.

How do I close it? (`Resources.UnloadAsset();` doesn't work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to see changes in the `Assets` made by any editor script immediately you should call [`AssetDatabase.Refresh();`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.Refresh.html) at the end of the acording method.

---

Afaik the contents of `Resources` folder(s) are **ReadOnly** in a build so you can't use

```
_xmlDoc.Save(PathOfFile);
```

in a build only in the Editor. You maybe should rather use the [StreamingAssets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) accesing it using [`Application.streamingAssetsPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html) or [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html).

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that it's only for Editor. How to use something same after build?